# Syntax Error On A Procedure ORA-01422

Tags: oracle

As a beginner, I am not able to see any error logically. All I am doing here is saving data into a variable and comparing that in if statements. However, at some point it returns more than requested rows and causes error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Late_Payment_Days(Inv_ID Varchar2) 
AS
    Payment_Exist Number;
    Late_Payment Number;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.Enable();
    SELECT Payment_Total 
    INTO Payment_Exist 
    FROM Invoices Where Invoice_ID = Inv_ID;

    SELECT 
        ( (SELECT PAYMENT_DATE FROM INVOICES WHERE INVOICE_ID = Inv_ID) 
          - (SELECT INVOICE_DUE_DATE FROM INVOICES WHERE INVOICE_ID= Inv_ID)
        )
    INTO Late_Payment 
    FROM Invoices;

    IF Payment_Exist=0 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No Payment!');

        IF Late_Payment > 0 THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Late_Payment || 'Overdue Days');
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Zero overdue days');
        END IF;
    END IF;
End;
/

Show Error;

EXEC Late_Payment_Days(5);
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this part is responsible for the error;

```
SELECT
    ( (SELECT PAYMENT_DATE FROM INVOICES WHERE INVOICE_ID = Inv_ID) 
      - (SELECT INVOICE_DUE_DATE FROM INVOICES WHERE INVOICE_ID= Inv_ID)
    )
INTO Late_Payment 
FROM Invoices;
```

If there is more than 1 row in `Invoices`, the result of the query will be many rows (with the same value) and we can only insert one value into the variable `Late_Payment`.

You can change the `FROM Invoices` to `FROM dual` (a special Oracle table with a single row):

```
SELECT
    ( (SELECT PAYMENT_DATE FROM INVOICES WHERE INVOICE_ID = Inv_ID) 
      - (SELECT INVOICE_DUE_DATE FROM INVOICES WHERE INVOICE_ID= Inv_ID)
    )
INTO Late_Payment 
FROM dual ;
```

or - since both subqueries use the same `FROM` and `WHERE` - simplify to:

```
SELECT PAYMENT_DATE - INVOICE_DUE_DATE 
INTO Late_Payment
FROM INVOICES 
WHERE INVOICE_ID = Inv_ID ;
```